# Kivy on Python 3.9

Tags: python, kivy

I can't install kivy on python 3.9, I've tried diferent ways but anyone function. I'm new in this world and i don't know anything of informatic. If somebody can can help me. Thanks. I have Windows 10.

Comment: i use Visual Code Studio

Comment: According to the [kivy website](https://kivy.org/#download) - "Python 2.7 and 3.5 to 3.7 is supported". Note that nothing later than 3.7  is listed.

Comment: I think the latest pre-release supports 3.9

Comment: I have the same problem what is the solution